# Problems using getline()

Tags: c++, file

I'm running out of hair to pull out, so I thought maybe someone here could help me with this frustration.

I'm trying to read a file line by line, which seems simple enough, using getline(). Problem is, my code seems to keep ignoring the \n, and putting the entire file into one string, which is problematic to say the least.

```
void MakeRandomLayout(int rows, int cols)
{
    string fiveByFive = "cubes25.txt";
    string fourByFour = "cubes16.txt";

    ifstream infile;

    while (true) {
        infile.open(fourByFour.c_str());
        if (infile.fail()) {
            infile.clear();
            cout << "No such file found";
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    Vector<string> cubes;
    string cube;
    while (std::getline(infile, cube)) {
        cubes.add(cube);
    }
}
```

Edits: Running OSX 10.7. 
The infinite loop for the file is unfinished, will eventually ask for a file.
No luck with extended getline() version, tried that earlier.
Same system for dev and build/run.

The text file i'm reading in looks as follows:

```
AAEEGN
ABBJOO
ACHOPS
AFFKPS
AOOTTW
CIMOTU
DEILRX
DELRVY
DISTTY
EEGHNW
EEINSU
EHRTVW
EIOSST
ELRTTY
HIMNQU
HLNNRZ
```

Each string is on a new line in the file. The second one that I'm not reading in is the same but `25` lines instead of `16`

Comment: Infinite loop if the file does not exist? nice.

Comment: What happens if you try this version of getline istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim ); ?

Comment: And were your files generated on the same system on which your program is running?

Comment: Just test the result of `getline`, instead of separately checking `fail`.

Comment: What does `Vector::add` look like? And, how do you know that it is all one string?

Comment: IIRC, the Mac line ending is `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: try changing the open call so that you specify binary and see if that works/helps

Comment: @BenVoigt That was true for Mac OS, but false for Mac OS X.

Comment: please update to your new code and post the txt files

Comment: Please post the code that makes you believe that all of the input lines are being joined into one string, and the code for `Vector::add`.

Comment: @Rob I'm pretty sure the code is there, the Vector<string> is holding elements of string typ, and calling the vector with [position] returns the element at the position inside the vector (like an array). When I call the cubes[0], i get the whole file.

Comment: So, either `Vector::add` is merging its input into the single 0th element, or you are falsely concluding that you get the whole file. Show us either code, or both, so that we can help you understand which is true. P.s. if `Vector` is from some published library, you could just tell us the name of the lib, and URL to the documentation.

Comment: try this string cube;
    while (std::getline(infile, cube)) {
        cout << cube << endl;
    } if its the vector ull know

Comment: @BenVoigt !! Got it, thanks man, i'm def running OSX 10.7, but '\r' as the delimiter solved the problem. Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: @wvm2008: Ok, written up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac software recognizes either `'\r'` or `'\n'` as line-endings, for backward compatibility with Mac OS Classic.   Make sure that your text editor hasn't put `'\r'` line endings in your file when your processing code is expecting `'\n'` (and verify that the `'\n'` characters you think are in the middle of the string aren't in fact `'\r'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are failing to display the contents of `Vector` correctly. When you dump the `Vector`, do you print a `\n` after each entry? You should, because `getline` discards the newlines on input.

FYI: the typical pattern for reading line-by-line is this:

```
Vector<string> cubes;
string cube;
while(std::getline(infile, cube)) {
  cubes.add(cube);
}
```

Note that this will discard the newlines, but will put one line per entry in Vector.

---

**EDIT:** For whatever it is worth, if you were using an `std::vector`, you could slurp the file in thusly:

```
std::ifstream ifile(av[1]);
std::vector<std::string> v(
  (std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifile)),
  std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

Comment: Inserted this code, and it has the same result as mine...The vector only has one element, and it's all of the lines, with the \n's